# Вывести элементы массива, имеющие одинаковые значения

Tags: javascript, массивы, поиск

Помогите пожалуйста, я тут пытаюсь колдовать с поиском одинаковых значений в массиве. Речь не о дубликатах, а именно о элементах массива, которые имеют большее количество копий, чем 1 (т. е. не [1, 1], a [1, 1, 1, 1, 1 и т. д.]).

У меня получилось вывести значения, имеющие только дубликаты:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 7, 4, 9, 9, 10, 3]

let uniq = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < i; j++)
        if (arr[j] === arr[i]) {
            uniq.push(arr[i])
        }
    }

    console.log(uniq)
```

но когда добавляется больше одинаковых значений в массив (например, число 9 в массиве), то код работает некорректно:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 7, 1, 4, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 3]

let uniq = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++)
    if (arr[j] === arr[i]) {
        uniq.push(arr[i])
    }
}

console.log(uniq)
```

выводя ещё больше этих девяток, а нужно, чтобы вывелся такой же результат как в предыдущем коде.

Хотелось бы код, в котором вообще не применяются методы поиска и фильтрации (метод push не считается ибо используется здесь для выведения имеющих копии чисел в новый массив и всё).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Фильтруем повторяющиеся хотя бы `copies` раз значения, используя `Map`:

```js
function foo(arr, copies) {
    let map = new Map();
    for (let elem of arr) {
        let counter = map.get(elem);
        map.set(elem, counter ? counter + 1 : 1);
    }
    let res = [];
    for (let [elem, counter] of map.entries())
        if (counter >= copies)
            res.push(elem);
    return res;
}

let arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 7, 4, 9, 9, 10, 3];
console.log(foo(arr, 1));
console.log(foo(arr, 2));
console.log(foo(arr, 3));
```

Решение без использования `Map` и методов поиска и фильтрации (в плане временной сложности алгоритма данное решение существенно уступает варианту с `Map`):

```js
function bar(arr, copies) {
    let res    = [];
    let unique = [];
    mainFor: for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        for (let elem of unique)
            if (elem === arr[i])
                continue mainFor;
        unique.push(arr[i]);
        let counter = 1;
        for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; ++j)
            counter += arr[j] === arr[i];
        if (counter >= copies)
            res.push(arr[i]);
    }
    return res;
}

let arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 7, 4, 9, 9, 10, 3];
console.log(bar(arr, 1));
console.log(bar(arr, 2));
console.log(bar(arr, 3));
```

Comment: Офигеть, круто! Этот ответ даже превзошёл мои ожидания. Спасибо огромное! С меня плюсик

Answer (score 1):

Чуть модифицировал ваш код:

```js
    const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 7, 1, 4, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 3]
    
    const uniqSet = new Set();
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < i; j++)
        if (arr[j] === arr[i]) {
            uniqSet.add(arr[i])
        }
    }
    
    const uniq = Array.from(uniqSet)
    
    console.log(uniq)
```

Comment: Тоже отлично, результат на который рассчитывал. :) Что-то я как-то не подумал про Set
Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

```
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

var a = ['a', 1, 'a', 2, '1', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 111];
var unique = a.filter(onlyUnique);

console.log(unique);
```

Взято с [английского SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Comment: Здесь отображается результат ["a", 1, 2, "1", "b", "c", 111], т. е. отсеиваются копии, а я хочу вывести только те значения, которые имеют копии, и без занесения их повторных значений в массив.
В данном массиве хотелось бы иметь такой результат - ["a", "b"]

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 1, 11, 4, 5, 6, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1, 9, 9, 10, 3, 11, 11]
const count = function (arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function (a, b) {
            return ({
                ...a,
                [b]: (a[b] || 0) + 1
            });
        }, {})
        ;
} 

const duplicates = function (dict) {
    return Object.keys(dict).filter(function (a) {
            return dict[a] > 1;
        });
}

console.log(count(arr))
console.log(duplicates(count(arr)).map(Number)) //результат.
```

Вот этот код даёт именно тот результат который я хотел. Но хотелось бы без этих мучений с преобразованием в объекты и чтобы в коде не использовались методы, если это возможно. Поэтому прошу о помощи в написании такого кода.

[Взято из qastack.ru](https://qastack.ru/programming/840781/get-all-non-unique-values-i-e-duplicate-more-than-one-occurrence-in-an-array)